# Channel mentions via MSteams Incoming Webhook connectors

Tags: microsoft-teams, webhooks

I am trying to use Channel mentions via MSteams Incoming Webhook connectors but it is not working for me. I am able to mention users but doing the same for Channel does not work. It simply gives me plain text.

I am following this link for JSON payload - https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Channel-Teams-mention-in-Adaptive-Cards/td-p/564320

Is this feature available for MSteams Incoming Webhook connectors ?

Comment: @Mention channel name using incoming webhook doesn't seem to be supported yet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#user-mention-in-incoming-webhook-with-adaptive-cards

Comment: Currently only user mention is supported in Incoming webhook. To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in [Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).